# how to use Multithreading in C# for constructors

Tags: c#, multithreading, constructor

I've an application which basically does 2 jobs:

> a) parses an XML (large number of contents) and serialize/de-serialize to
>   a class object and it does some mathematical operations over the data
>   obtained
>
> b) populates the UI by parsing a number of files/directories.

Both are independent tasks.
As execution time is long here, I want to use multithreading here in my form where I call a contructor of another class (that does XML parsing and operations). 
Can you please guide how to do that?

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
public Binarylist bList = new Binarylist(); //parses the XML and does multiple operations
........
.......
private Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
........ //populates UI by parsing files & directories
}
```

My question here - how do i multithread Binarylist contructor so that I also execute form1_load in parallel on the main thread?

Answer (score 3):

Use a Backgroundworker.

Pass the constructed list to the Completed event and assign it to the formclass field there.

Make sure the rest of your Form checks `bList == null` when appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not get you - can you pl elaborate with a sample code?

Comment: Can you please use full words?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate BinaryList on a background thread following these steps:

1. Create a method for that invokes BinaryList constructor

   ```
   private void getBinaryList()
   {
   bList = new BinaryList();
   }
   ```
2. Initiate new thread execution when form start loading before doing anything else:

   ```
   private Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(getBinaryList));
   t.Start();


   // do your stuff

   t.Join();
   //this ensures both threads complete before event execution finishes
   }
   ```

If both of these jobs are time consuming I would advise against locking UI thread as your app will become unresponsive so I would execute both on background thread and update you UI after.

Comment: Thanks. I get this error "Start Index cannot be less than Zero", Paramter name = "StartIndex". I do not understand this warning (or error) while running my application. Could you please help?

Comment: this is not related to threading. It must be somewhere in your logic code. Are you using substring function?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use [tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx):

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    private readonly Task<Binarylist> bList = 
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new Binarylist());

    private Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the result of the task when needed
        var constructedList = bList.Result;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Accessing [`Task.Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) will wait for the construction to finish and then give you the fully constructed object. Arguably, your `Binarylist` class could use tasks to do its expensive initialization.

Comment: problem here is => bList is not created as a Binarylist instead, it's created as a Task object. Hence, I'm not able to access the class members using bList which gives me error.

Comment: As the code above shows - you get to the actual list through task's Result property. Then you can access the class members in the usual way.